# Django Captcha Ask User To Enter The Next Letter / Number For Each Character Of Random / Specified Length Challenge

Tags: python, django, captcha

Code:

```
def captcha_challenge():
    challenge = u''
    response = u''
    for i in range(4):
        digit = random.randint(0,9)
        lower_upper_alphabet = string.ascii_letters
        random_letter = random.choice(lower_upper_alphabet)
        challenge += str(digit)
        response += str((digit + 1) % 10)
    return challenge, response
```

​This captcha code currently will display random 4 numbers and ask the user to enter the next number that comes after each number shown.

​Z would be A and single digit number 9 would be 0
​

Examples:
​

Current Captcha Challenge:

```
1389
```

​
Current Response Solution:

```
2490
```

Desired Captcha Challenge:

```
1zbg

gua16k

wd46ugcq32
```

Desired Response Solution:

```
2ach

hvb27l

xe57vhdr43
```

My question is how do I get the captcha to show a random length challenge of 10 characters or less each page refresh with both letters and numbers? Where no matter what character is displayed, the user will have to enter the next letter or number that comes after that particular character to solve the captcha?

Answer (score 0):

Try to be a bit clearer on your question. I think you should try the `random` module and use `random.choice()` to generate a choice for the captchas.

Comment: sorry I will try to clarify. I want to combine letters and numbers into the challenge and response. Right now the code only handles 4 numbers. I would also like to randomly change the length of the challenge and response each time the page is refreshed. The user needs to enter the next letter or number for each character shown in the challenge for the response to work.

Comment: For that you can use for i in range(random.randint(1, 10))

Comment: That solves the randomly generated amount of characters but how do i combine letters into the code?

Comment: How would I implement the following? random.choices(string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase)
{c: string.ascii_lowercase[(i + 1) % len(string.ascii_loewrcase)] for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)}

Answer (score 0):

Could `django-simple-captcha` help?

https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#roll-your-own